# Why NearestNeighborGraph gives different result for numerical List and exact List

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In mathematica 10.3 there is a function called `NearestNeighborGraph`. I found some behavior of it that I don't understand.

First I generate a 2D list like this

```
Clear[latticeGen];
latticeGen[primitiveVec_List, numofcell_List, 
  base_List] := (tmptmp = Transpose[base];
  Flatten[
   Transpose[(# + tmptmp) & /@ (Tuples[
        Range /@ numofcell].primitiveVec), {1, 3, 2}], 1])
lattice = 
  latticeGen[{{3/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {3/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}}, {10, 
    10}, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}];
```

Now I use `NearestNeighborGraph` on numerical list

```
NearestNeighborGraph[N@lattice, {All, 1.001}]
```

gives

[image]

While on exact list

```
NearestNeighborGraph[lattice, {All, 1.001}]
```

gives

[image]

What is wrong here?

---

**Update**

ciao has pointed out by setting `GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"`, the second graph will be normal. But the problem remain. Why dealing with exact list, we have to add this option? What does this option mean? What does it do? Why the distortions especially at the edge of the graph?

Comment: Add `GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"`...

Comment: @ciao Oh, my god. There are so many `GraphLayout`. I can't understand even one of them. Why it has something to do with numerical and exact points?

Comment: Beats me - the vagaries of "automatic" defaults are generally a bit of a "pay no attention to the man behind the curtain" kind of thing. When in doubt, tell it what you want...

Comment: @ciao Thank you very much : )

Comment: Since your source data is actually in the Euclidean plane you could just pass the coordinate pairs to the `VertexCoordinates` option to set them manually instead of relying on the somewhat undocumented graph layout options. (Don't have 10.3 available right now, so I can't test it with `NearestNeighborGraph` unfortunately.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Hi, MartinBüttner. Actually `GraphLayout ` and `SpringEmbedding` appears in the doc page. However, the issue I concern is why it behaves differently on exact and numerical data, I can't understand

Comment: Smells like a bug, I would report it.